# Add source of my project A to my project B maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have 2 maven projects, `Faction` and `Games`.`Games` depends of `Faction`, so there's the dependency in my `pom.xml`.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.onima</groupId>
  <artifactId>onimaFaction</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

They both are a project of my workspace.

Whenever I change the code in `Faction`, I would like to have the changes also in `API` and not install every changes, do you know how to do?

**EDIT:**
This is working for one project, but not for the other see :
Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Assuming you're talking about running from within Eclipse itself, check whether you have *workspace dependency resolution* turned on. (Under "Maven Dependencies", you should see a project folder for the other project instead of a jar.)

Comment: Edited my original post, check it out

Comment: Okay, it now sounds like you don't have your dependencies defined in the correct sequence. Physically draw bubbles on a piece of paper with arrows from one to another (and make sure you don't have a loop).

Comment: If I understood what you mean, I have `Faction` which also has `API` as a dependency. I don't think there's a loop as `Faction` is declared first in my Game `pom.xml`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you describe a situation when you work on one project that has two modules,
In maven its called a multi-module project.
So basically you need to create a module with a packagine 'pom' that will list two modules:
 - Games
 - Faction

Each module will have its own 'src/main/....' layout as well as its own pom.xml.
All in all the project will look like this:

```
my-project
|___ pom.xml
|___ [ games ]
|    |___ pom.xml
|    |___ src/{main/test} etc.
|___ [ faction ]
     |___  pom.xml
     |___ src/{main/test} etc.
```

The 'root' pom.xml should look like this (snippet that illustrates the multi module only):

```
<groupId>...</groupId>
<artifactId>...<groupId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<modules>
   <module>games</module>
   <module>faction</module>
</modules>
```

The poms for games and faction modules should be like you have now.

Then, open the 'root' pom as a project in an IDE and you should be set.

Comment: Thank you very much. As you might have understood I'm very new to maven and I'm still having issues with it (I hate Apache's doc I don't know why). I'm going to find a tutorial on modules and I'll hit you up if I understood everything :)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you'r trying to do is make Games a Module of Faction:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.yourdomain</groupId>
    <artifactId>faction</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
            <module>games</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

where Games has its own pom.xml/project and can be in a subdirectory in the Faction directory.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.yourdomain</groupId>
    <artifactId>games</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <dependencies.../>
</project>
```

Comment: And if I clean install all this, will I have 2 different jars ?

Comment: Yes.  I currently do this with 1 project "microservice-suite" which has 4 modules (microservices).  From the microservice-suite directory I can run: 'mvn clean install' and I end up with 4 jar files (my microservice-suite has no code other than the pom.xml)

Comment: I still have all the files as .class [dependencies](http://prntscr.com/m7q6dd), see my `Faction`'s [`pom.xml`](https://ghostbin.com/paste/pn4vs)

See my `Games` 's[`pom.xml`](https://ghostbin.com/paste/cjfj2)

Although my Games is not a subdirectory of Factions, I would like to keep them separated. Can I ?

Comment: Ok so I tried what you did as much as I could, and I found out that it's not really what I was looking for (maybe I'm wrong). I just want to have the src in my maven dependencies (the classical java project way doesn't work). Thanks for any kind of help again

Comment: Your Faction/pom.xml has a dependency on Games/pom.xml (great!).  The problem is that your Games also has a dependency back to Faction causing a cyclical dependency.  I think removing that should work as you expect.